# how do I call up a pdf file on a specific bookmark in python?

Tags: pdf, python-2.7, pypdf

I want to find a file in a folder, find a specific bookmark in that file, and when the right information is entered (for example "file 7, bookmark 5") the file will open to the right spot. (in python)

I've found this:

```
path_to_pdf = os.path.abspath(filename)

path_to_acrobat = os.path.abspath('C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 10.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe')

process = subprocess.Popen([path_to_acrobat, '/A', 'page=' + page, path_to_pdf], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
```

but it only finds pages, not bookmarks

there seems to be a way to do this with [pyPdf2](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/tree/416eac9dbc492f9a47890e4ae2979ce6cf1eec9f) but I can't find documentation

Comment: Please show what you have already found or what you have tried so far.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can use something like `acrobat.exe foo.pdf#bookmark`. Obviously, you need the name of the bookmark, there’s not much point in jumping to the fifth one – which way do you count them, chronologically?

Comment: yes, "bookmark 5" was a poor example, think of "chapter 5" or whatever, how exactly would I use this code?